# MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 Calculator bugged?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, calculator

Am i crazy or the native calculator on MacOS Sierra is not working ? 
For instance, if i want to sum 10 + 20 , i do the follwoing :

```
1 - Type '10'
2 - Type '+'
3 - Type '20'
4 - Type 'Enter'
```

What calculator does after the step 4 is to REPEAT the '20', instead of giving me the correct result (30) :

[image]

This problem started after upgrade to Sierra 10.12.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deactivate "Reverse Polish Notation" in the menu :)

Otherwise you have to enter "10 Enter 20 +" to get 30. It's operating with a stack in RPN mode.

To be fair, there *is* a kind of bug in RPN mode - pressing "+" with only one operand on the stack should have signaled an error to you (as "+" operation in RPN is defined as fetching *two* operands from stack, adding them, and pushing the result back on the stack). HP calculators would not allow this.

Comment: Thank you, actually the option is on View > RPN mode. After deactivate this, worked as i expected :D

Comment: @delphirules thanks, didn't have an english OSX here, thus the diffuse description ;)